# How to exclude rows with blank info in one column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view, report

I have this script

```
USE [KevinMayhewLive]
GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[KM_SALES_DATA]    Script Date: 06/27/2017 10:23:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[KM_SALES_DATA]
--Natika Edward 28/03/17
--Pull Sales Order Data
AS

 SELECT
 "SL_ACCOUNTS"."CUCODE"  AS [Customer Code],
  "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_ORDER_NUMBER" AS [Order Number],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),"ORD_DETAIL"."OD_DATE_PUTIN",103) AS [Date of 
Purchase],
    "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_STOCK_CODE" AS [Item],
     "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_QTYORD" AS [Quantity Ordered],
      "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_UNITCST" AS [Unit Cost],
       "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_GROSS" AS [C_AMT_SALES], 
        "ORD_HEADER"."OH_USER2" AS [Order Origin],
        "CRM_CAMPAIGN"."CMP_CODE" AS [Campaign Code]
 FROM   (("KevinMayhewLive"."dbo"."ORD_DETAIL" "ORD_DETAIL" 
 INNER JOIN "KevinMayhewLive"."dbo"."ORD_HEADER" "ORD_HEADER" ON 
"ORD_DETAIL"."OD_ORDER_NUMBER"="ORD_HEADER"."OH_ORDER_NUMBER") 
 INNER JOIN "KevinMayhewLive"."dbo"."CRM_CAMPAIGN" "CRM_CAMPAIGN" ON 
"ORD_HEADER"."OH_CAMPAIGN_LINK"="CRM_CAMPAIGN"."CMP_PRIMARY") 
 INNER JOIN "KevinMayhewLive"."dbo"."SL_ACCOUNTS" "SL_ACCOUNTS" ON 
"ORD_HEADER"."OH_ACCOUNT"="SL_ACCOUNTS"."CUCODE"
 --where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),"ORD_DETAIL"."OD_DATE_PUTIN",103) = 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103) --take out hyphens to run report and 
bring back daily figures.
```

To pull sales order data, it also includes postage and text lines which have no stock code, I need to exclude these lines where there is no code..... ANy ideas?

Comment: did you try something like : `where <column_name> IS NOT NULL OR <column_name> <> ''`

Comment: where would I put this, coming up with errors when I try and add it

Comment: added at the end with the date code, ' ' are coming up red and its not working

Comment: Put `WHERE "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_STOCK_CODE IS NOT NULL OR "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_STOCK_CODE" <> ''"` at the end of code.

Comment: yep all good thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `WHERE "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_STOCK_CODE IS NOT NULL OR "ORD_DETAIL"."OD_STOCK_CODE" <> ''` at the end of your code.